# Send file from Node using Express within a POST route

Tags: node.js, express

I need to send the client (browser) a file after the client invokes a POST endpoint within my API. I tried using `res.download(filename)` but while there's no error, it doesn't do anything, e.g., pop up a download dialog, open in default viewer, etc.

```
function onArchiveCompleted (res, zip) {
    const archive = `${uuidv4()}.zip``zip.writeZip(archive)
    res.download(archive)
}
```

The "res.download()" returns 200 but no file dialog is ever presented on the client. However, if you look in the Network panel (browser developer tools) you can see that the file contents were returned.

What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: Try `res.sendFile`.

Comment: How does your client invoke the POST endpoint? A download by the browser will be triggered only if the POST request results from submitting an HTML form.